# How can I imwrite a double in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am producing 3500x7500 size double matrices in a loop that I want to export as tif files.

A section of the code

```
for k = 1:length(basinlist{1})
    #some operation that produces GRID
    imwrite(GRID,filename);
end
```

But, when I do this, the TIF file produced contains only 255 and output is in uint8. I read about it in the documentation, but I am not able to fix it. All I want is to retain the original values with no scaling or anything.

If this helps:

```
>> max(max(GRID))

ans =

   1.5646e+04

>> min(min(GRID))

ans =

   1.1119e+03
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want to create image with such colour depth that will fit to given data.

Data exported to image format are converted to `uint8` by default (data range 0-2^8-1).

But Matlab (2011b) can operate with more `uintX` formats where `X` stands for X bits per value.

- `uint8` with span 0-255 (2^8)
- `uint16` with span 0-65 535 (2^16)
- `uint32` with span 0-4.29 e 9 (2^32)
- `uint64` with span 0-1.84 e 19 (2^64)

Code to export data without any loss:

```
for k = 1:length(basinlist{1})
  #some operation that produces GRID

  %% Convert GRID to roughest acceptable uint format
  GRID=uint16(GRID);

  %% Export
  imwrite(GRID,filename);
end
```

Comment: This converts the floats to integers. How can I preserve the floats?

Comment: But if you import the file exported by `geotiffwrite` it will be `uint8` class aswell. So you will lose float anyway... If you want to keep float you have to use different file format. Both `imwrite` and `geotiffwrite` check the input format and if it is **not `uintX`** it turn it to `uint8` format.